# multiple plots of time series in one graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

i have data like this

```
  var1<- rnorm(100, 5, 10)
  var2<- rnorm(100, 300, 45)
  country <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","k","l"),each=10)
  year <- rep(2000:2009,length.out=10)
  data1 <-data.frame(country,year,var1,var2)
```

I would like to make one big graph with many small plots, in each to see line of var1 and var2 over time, where each small graph would correspond for one country. Ideally it would be optional to set number of collumns, lets say 4 collumns of grpahs and size/shape of big one, as i have much more countries than here and i will have to adjust for that..

Many thanks

Comment: check `?facet_wrap` and `?facet_grid` in `ggplot2`. The docs are very good and there are plenty of examples in SO.

Comment: It's really better for you to show what you've tried. You might find tutorials by searching online for small multiples, try something, and then post what hasn't worked more specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A usual way would be to bring data in long format and use `facet_wrap`/`facet_grid` to create multiple small plots. You can use `ncol` and `nrow` to specify how to format the plots.

```
library(tidyverse)

data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = var1:var2) %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(year, value, color = name, group = name) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~country, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot!  can i set the years to be below each graph instead of bottom of the last and export it to pdf?

Comment: You can set `scales = 'free'` in `facet_wrap` to get numbers below each graph like this `facet_wrap(~country, ncol = 2, scales = 'free')`. To get it in pdf save the output of above plot in a variable `p1 <- data1 %>%pivot_longer(cols = var1:var2) ........` and use `ggsave('temp.pdf', p1)`